# Comparing Two Functions for Recursive Digit Sum

Tags: python

I'm stumped as to why my solution for the Recursive Digit Sum question on HackerRank is being rejected.

## Background

**The question:**

For an input of string n and integer k, the number h is created by concatenating n "k" times. Find the "super digit" of h by recursively summing the integers until one is left.

**For example:**

- n = '9875', k = 2, so h = 98759875
- sum(98759875)= 58
- sum(58)= 13
- sum(13) = 4

## Submissions

### My Solution

```
def superDigit(n, k):
    h=n*k
    while len(h)>1:
        h=str(sum([int(i) for i in h]))
    return int(h)
```

### Solution I've Found

```
def superDigit(n, k):
    return 1 + (k * sum(int(x) for x in n) - 1) % 9
```

## My Inquiry to the Community

What am I missing in my solution? Yes it's not as simple as the supplied solution involving the digital root function (which I don't fully understand, I just found it online) but I don't see how my function is supplying incorrect answers. It passes most of the test cases but is rejecting for 1/3 of them.

Comment: if n = 9875 and k = 2 then "98759875" then your code already wrong. why did you put n * k it will be 19750, or is the "n" a string? it's quite unclear

Comment: What are the types of `n` and `k`?  int or str, or a mix?

Comment: @P-Sides can you share the testcases in which it showing incorrect answer

Comment: @wim by seeing his example i can say `n type(str)` and `k type(int)` as ex `n = 9875, k = 2, so h = 98759875` n must be string if k will be string and n is int than output will be 222.... upto 9875 times

Comment: You don't have to duplicate the string.  You can find the digit sum of the original string and then multiply that by "k" (reducing if the product is > 10).

Comment: In the problem statement, n can have 100000 digits and k goes up to 10^5. Your code may simply be timing out or cause an out of memory exception.

Comment: @owenizedd n is a string and k is an integer. I have updated the post, sorry for the missing info.

Comment: When trying to debug it's always helpful to use print statements to see where your output deviates from the expected output. But my guess is Paul is right and this is a problem with the numbers getting too big, causing memory issues. Just knowing that taking mod 9 keeps the sum of digits the same is super useful here and essentially what the provided answer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some helpful comments from @Tim Roberts, @Paul Hankin, and @yagod I was able to solve the issue. It was in fact due to time-out! All I had to do was update one line: `h=str(sum([int(i) for i in n])*(k%9))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result of my research on your case:

You don't supply the typing, so I had to case check to find out you use one `str` and one `int`. How do I know this?

Well if you used 2 `str`s the multiplication would fail:

```
>>> "10"*"2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

And if you used 2 `int`s, `h` would also be an int, and your `sum` would fail:

```
>>> str(sum([int(i) for i in 100]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So as a result you must have one int and one str. But that also doesn't work since the `int`*`str` multiplication uses concatenation instead of the "mathematical" addition:

```
>>> 10 * "2"
'2222222222'
```

My solution suggestion is simply to:

1. Use typing for clarity
2. Use `int`s for the multiplication and `str`s for splitting the digits

This can be done simply by editing only the first two lines:

```py
def superDigit(n: int, k:int) -> int:
    h=str(n*k)
    while len(h)>1:
        h=str(sum([int(i) for i in h]))
    return int(h)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: by seeing his example Initially i can say n type(str) and k type(int) as ex n = 9875, k = 2, so h = 98759875 n must be string if k will be string and n is int than output will be 222.... upto 9875 times.. what you think?

Comment: Oh, that's right. I didn't use the comment. Well not that it really matter, but this is a great example where `typing` will greatly facilitate the code readability :)

Comment: just wanted to know his saying "It passes most of the test cases but is rejecting for 1/3 of them." can you give example of the testcases in which his code giving wrong answer

Comment: It's on `HackerRank` so I don't think he has access to the broken test cases. HackerRank only lets you see the first few.

Comment: @scr I just updated the posting. n is a string and k is an integer. Very sorry about this missing information.

Comment: @Yash Mehta I will try to find a way to access the broken test cases. This is on HackerRank so certain cases remained 'locked' until you meet a condition.